# CakePHP 3, Get an error when loading script

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I trying to load script files that are located on the `webroot` folder.
The loading is successfull but the problem is that all the script are loaded with this content at the beginning of the file :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
>   Host: localhost:8765 
>  Date: Sun, 09 Sep 2018
>   15:07:31 +0000 
>  Connection: close 
>  Content-Type:
>   application/javascript 
>  Content-Length: 5615

That content actually display on every script loaded and doesn't let the script run correctly.

Comment: so your app displays http `headers` somewhere while loading js, is that your issue?

Comment: It's actually write http headers on my js files. It's normally working when i do it on a remote server.